# Android webrtc SIGSEGV errors

Tags: webrtc-android

I'm trying to build webrtc android app using `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006` but sometimes I'm getting `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)` errors.

Description of errors:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000004d6f10  /data/app/com.xxx/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x6d5000) (Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnection_nativeClose+32)
  #00  pc 0000000000648881  /data/app/com.xxx/oat/arm64/base.vdex

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000002ebfa6  /data/app/com.xxx/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x435000)
  #00  pc 0000000000038863  /data/app/com.xxx/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x38000)
```

The first error's keyword is `Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnection_nativeClose` but I couldn't find anything. Any idea of how to manage these errors and fix them?